# Angular for loop inside {{ }}

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="SrfAssets">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>AssetID</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    {{ element["srfAssets"].at(0)["assetId"] }},
    {{ element["srfAssets"].at(1)["assetId"] }}
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

How can this be done using for loop.
This is how element looks like:-

```
[{ ...,
srfAssets:[{assetId:'abc',...},...]
},
...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of element["srfAssets"]; let i = index">
  {{item.at(i)["assetId"]}}{{i === element["srfAssets"].length - 1 ? '' : ', '}}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: just a small adjustments should be done `i === element["srfAssets"].length - 1`

Comment: of course, thank you

Comment: You can also use `{{element.srfAssets.join(',')}}` or `{{element.srfAssets.join('<br/>')}}`

Answer (score 0):

Table inside a table worked but it doesn't looks really nice.

```
     <ng-container matColumnDef="SrfAssets">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>AssetID</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <table mat-table [dataSource]="element['srfAssets']">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="AssetID">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                {{ element["assetId"] }}
              </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['AssetID']"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['AssetID']"></tr>
          </table>
          <!-- {{ element["srfAssets"].at(0)["assetId"] }},
          {{ element["srfAssets"].at(1)["assetId"] }} -->
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

[image: Table image]